# openFileOutput FileNotFoundException

Tags: android

This is my noob question for the week. I'm looking more for general speculation than specific code and maybe hoping the Android folks are watching and could correct this:

the SDK documentation for Context.openFileOutput says:

> Open a private file associated with this Context's application package for writing. Creates the file if it doesn't already exist.

Ok, that sounds good. I can create a file. Except this method also throws a FileNotFoundException, so apparently something is amiss. Why would a function that is *supposed* to create a file if it's not found throw an exception if the file is not found???

Kinda defeats that whole "Creates the file..." thing, doesn't it?

Comment: What path are you providing to `openFileOutput()`?

Comment: can you run a debugger and check what is the <code>detailMessage</code> of your FileNotFoundException? you cannot use file separators in the method call (its stated in the docs, and in that case detailMessage is "File [...] contains a path separator").

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have to apologize for leaping before I looked on this one. I kinda panicked while reading the documentation. After some testing, I found that `openFileOutput()` does, in fact, work as advertised and *will* create a file if it's not found, not just throw an FnF exception as I feared. Apparently, the FnF throw was added in case the Activity's application directory does not exist.

Again, my apologies but hopefully, this might help others who are confused by the documentation.

Comment: FileNotFoundException will also be thrown if there is a permissions problem that prevents the file from being created/opened.

Comment: @MattConnolly Then why is it called a "FileNotFoundException" ?

Comment: `openFileOutput` is declared as throwing only that exception. Beats me why they choose not to throw a more appropriate exception in other circumstances.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: Another problems that I have right now, with Private file creation mode, it throws a Mono.Android exception "Operation is not supported" when the file doesn't exists. Have you ever encounter this?

Comment: I believe a `FileNotFoundException` will also be thrown if a directory exists with the same name, making it impossible to create the file. And yes, the name is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

FileNotFoundException is an exception thrown in case that you are trying to write to a file that does not exist, or cannot be currently accessed. When else would this occur?

- Perhaps you forgot to close the file, and tried to open the same file.
- Perhaps you tried to create multiple FileOutputStream objects pointing to the same file.

These will result in a FileNotFoundException.

Anyway, you can insert a `throws FileNotFoundException` at the end of your function declaration where you call openFileOutput (and to other functions that call this function).

Answer (score 1):

Possibly also thrown if you use MODE_APPEND, which appends to an existing file and the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score -4):

Have you inserted the right Permission? 
see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html
for reference. 
i think

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

could be the one You are fine with

Comment: That permission is for external storage; `openFileOutput()` is for internal storage.

Comment: @CommonsWare if that is true, then what permission do we need to write to internal storage...?

Comment: @edthethird: There is no permission required to write to internal storage.

Comment: k, thanks.  Must be doing something else wrong.   I am getting this error every update, as opposed to just the first one (which should be creating the file)