# android openFileOutput and file not created

Tags: android

I have a problem with the openFileOutput method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)

The documentation mentionned : "Creates the file if it doesn't already exist"

And I get this error :

```
System.err                    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/****/files/conf.properties: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)                                                                                                 
System.err                    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)                                                               
System.err                    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)                                                   
System.err                    at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:642)                                               
System.err                    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:159)                                     
System.err                    at com.ecab.file.ManageText.getString(ManageText.java:25)                                                    
System.err                    at com.ecab.ConnectionActivity.initTexts(ConnectionActivity.java:67)                                         
System.err                    at com.ecab.ConnectionActivity.setAfterViews(ConnectionActivity.java:61)                                     
System.err                    at com.ecab.ConnectionActivity_.afterSetContentView_(ConnectionActivity_.java:105)                           
System.err                    at com.ecab.ConnectionActivity_.setContentView(ConnectionActivity_.java:111)                                 
System.err                    at com.ecab.ConnectionActivity_.onCreate(ConnectionActivity_.java:32)                                        
System.err                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)                                                    
System.err                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)                               
System.err                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)                                
System.err                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104)                                 
System.err                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132)                                            
System.err                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157)                                      
System.err                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)                                                       
System.err                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)                                                                   
System.err                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)                                                 
System.err                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)                                                      
System.err                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)                                                          
System.err                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)                           
System.err                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)                                              
System.err                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)                                                             
System.err                    Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)                        
System.err                    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)                                                                      
System.err                    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)                                                       
System.err                    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)                                                               
System.err                    ... 23 more
```

I found a similar post here : [openFileOutput FileNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034575/openfileoutput-filenotfoundexception) but there is no reason to explain the problem. so my question is why my file is not created if it doesn't exist ?

Comment: Are you sure of the path of the file ?
Can you show us the manifest permissions ?

[See also this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625837/android-what-is-wrong-with-openfileoutput), because it seems to be the same question

Comment: Yes i'm sure of the path. The link is just a context problem. If I create the file on my rooted phone (with adb shell), there is no problem.